# Listbox Filter using a combobox

Tags: excel, vba, filter, combobox, listbox

I am new to VBA and I'm currently making a userform that filters all data based off of a combobox value which works but only pulls 1 row of data instead of all rows with the same cell value I.E Column C.

I'm trying to have it search for the combobox criteria in Column C and display all rows with the same cell value in the listbox.

```
 Option Explicit

 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim lrow As Long
 Dim i As Long, j As Long
 Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

 '~~> Set this to the relevant worksheet
 Set ws = Sheet1

 '~~> Set the listbox column count
 ListBox1.ColumnCount = 7

 Dim col As New Collection
 Dim itm As Variant

 With ws
    '~~> Get last row in column C
    lrow = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    '~~> Create a unique list from column C values
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 2 To lrow
        col.Add .Range("C" & i).Value2, CStr(.Range("C" & i).Value2)
    Next i
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    '~~> Add the item to combobox
    For Each itm In col
       ComboBox1.AddItem itm
    Next itm
 End With
 End Sub

 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 '~~> If nothing selected in the combobox then exit
  If ComboBox1.ListIndex = -1 Then Exit Sub

'~~> Clear the listbox
ListBox1.Clear

Dim DataRange As Range, rngArea As Range
Dim DataSet As Variant

With ws
    '~~> Remove any filters
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    
    '~~> Find last row in Col C
    lrow = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    '~~> Filter on the relevant column
    With .Range("C1:C" & lrow)
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=ComboBox1.Value
        
        On Error Resume Next
        Set DataRange = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
    
    '~~> Check if the autofilter returned any results
    If Not DataRange Is Nothing Then
        '~~> Instead of using another object, I am reusing the object
        Set DataRange = .Range("A2:G" & lrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        
        '~~> Create the array
        ReDim DataSet(1 To DataRange.Areas.Count + 1, 1 To 7)
        
        j = 1
        
        '~~> Loop through the area and store in the array
        For Each rngArea In DataRange.Areas
            For i = 1 To 7
                DataSet(j, i) = rngArea.Cells(, i).Value2
            Next i
            j = j + 1
        Next rngArea
        
        '~~> Set the listbox list
        ListBox1.List = DataSet
    End If
    
    '~~> Remove any filters
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your logic in the 'Create the array' and 'Loop through the area and store in the array' isn't right so your not picking up every row you need. Try replacing those two sections of code with these

```
'~~> Create the array
Dim rowCount As Long
For Each rngArea In DataRange.Areas
    rowCount = rowCount + rngArea.Rows.count
Next rngArea
ReDim DataSet(1 To rowCount, 1 To 7)
```

```
'~~> Loop through the area and store in the array
Dim row As Long, index As Long
For row = 2 To lrow
    If Not Intersect(DataRange, .Cells(row, "C")) Is Nothing Then
        index = index + 1
        For i = 1 To 7
            DataSet(index, i) = .Cells(row, i).Value2
        Next i
    End If
Next row
```

... keep everything else as-is

Comment: No problem. If you feel the answer solved your problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the check mark. This helps keep the focus on older questions which still don't have answers.